# Redirect from HTTP to HTTPS with respect to the X-Forwarded-For header (SSL termination used)

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, http, redirect, https

I'm looking to redirect from HTTP to HTTPS. My Nginx server sits behind a load balancer which will terminate SSL for me and send all traffic (HTTP and HTTPS) to port 80. The only evidence I will have to indicate whether the original request made was HTTP or HTTPS is via the `X-Forwarded-For` header that is set by the load balancer. Is there a built-in, inexpensive way to handle redirection in Nginx when the original request was on HTTP? Keep in mind, I'll only have a server set up for port 80.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you're guaranteeing that the X-Forwarded-For header is only set for SSL traffic ...

```
if ($http_x_forwarded_for) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

Although this is arguably something you should do at the balancer.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up deciding that termination of SSL at the LB isn't a good idea for my use-case and instead will be creating a 80 and a 443 server in Nginx.

Comment: One thing to note about terminating SSL at the nginx layer, you'll likely lose the client IP altogether with that solution. It depends on the load-balancer you're using, but if you're load-balancing SSL, then you'll need to do TCP-level load-balancing (as opposed to HTTP-level). Best of luck :)

Comment: Oh :/ thanks again, that's good to know. Man, people like you make the tech world go round.